# I am trying to set form values of template driven form, but getting error as shown below Error:

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to set form values in ngOnInit() method. But getting error -
ERROR Error: 
        There are no form controls registered with this group yet.  If you're using ngModel,
        you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).

```
ngOnInit() {
// this.index = +this.route.snapshot.params['index'];
// console.log("index value in form is "+this.index);
this.subscription = this.sharedService.startedEditing
  .subscribe((index: number) => {
       this.editIndex = index;
        this.editMode = true;
        this.editedTestCase = 
this.sharedService.getTestCase(this.editIndex);
        console.log("Inside ngonint for editing ");
        console.log(this.editedTestCase);

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.testForm.setValue({
            testid: this.editedTestCase.testid,
            testPriority: this.editedTestCase.testPriority,
            testSummary: this.editedTestCase.testSummary
        });
        });


     this.router.navigate(['form']);     
  });
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion guys?

Comment: unable to load data in form @Soufiane

Comment: please show us more code. especially your template html and initialization logic of this.testFotm